# "Cannot begin test transaction because we are already inside one"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I followed [this tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-a-phoenix-elixir-json-api) and my simple test always fail with this error

```
1) test /index returns a list of contacts (WorldNote.ChatsControllerTest)                                             
     test/controllers/chats_controller_test.exs:16                                                                      
     ** (RuntimeError) cannot begin test transaction because we are already inside one                                  
     stacktrace:                                                                                                        
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:321: anonymous fn/6 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.start_test_transaction/3                
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:615: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.pool_transaction/4                                        
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:314: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.start_test_transaction/3                                  
       test/controllers/chats_controller_test.exs:9: WorldNote.ChatsControllerTest.__ex_unit_setup_0/1                  
       test/controllers/chats_controller_test.exs:1: WorldNote.ChatsControllerTest.__ex_unit__/2
```

The code is quite simple

```
defmodule WorldNote.ChatsControllerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false
  use Plug.Test
  alias WorldNote.Chats
  alias WorldNote.Repo
  alias Ecto.Adapters.SQL

  setup do
    SQL.begin_test_transaction(Repo)

    on_exit fn ->
      SQL.rollback_test_transaction(Repo)
    end
  end

  test "/index returns a list of contacts" do
    contacts_as_json =
      %Chats{fbid: 1234567890, latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0, content: "yo"}
      |> Repo.insert
      |> List.wrap
      |> Poison.encode!

    response = conn(:get, "/api/contacts") |> send_request

    assert response.status == 200
    assert response.resp_body == contacts_as_json
  end

  defp send_request(conn) do
    conn
    |> put_private(:plug_skip_csrf_protection, true)
    |> WorldNote.Endpoint.call([])
  end
end
```

I googled all over the error `cannot begin test transaction because we are already inside one`. But couldn't find any fix.

PS. Im using Postgresql

Comment: What was your fix for this issue? I've just updated from Phoenix_Ecto 0.3 to 0.4 and now I'm getting this issue on every test :( - even in my model test which doesn't use the controllers

Comment: Like @JoseValim said. Remove the whole part with test transactions. ExUnit does it automatically since some update

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you using latest Phoenix? If so, it is supposed to have generated `test/support/conn_case.ex` which already has all the steps required to run your controller tests. You just need to do `use YourApp.ConnCase` in your tests. The blog post was written before the testing infrastructure was in place. :)

That said, the reason is likely because `test/test_helper.exs` already has a call to `begin_test_transaction`.

Comment: Yup. As always You've been first Jose.
Thanks a lot :D